# log4net shows the header and footer to often

Tags: c#, log4net

I use log4net in a module as a static object of a WCF service.

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service));
```

I also configured header and footer:

```
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <header value="&#13;&#10;Session start&#13;&#10;" />
            <footer value="Session end&#13;&#10;" />
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%5thread] %-5level %c %m%n"/>
    </layout>
```

Sometimes the time between outputs to the log file may be larger than 10 sec.

I see the log output

```
2022-02-10 14:30:59,543 [    9] DEBUG ...
2022-02-10 14:30:59,543 [    9] INFO  ...
Session end

Session start
2022-02-10 14:43:01,118 [    7] INFO  ...
```

I can see the the Service object it self is created an disposed. But what about the static member inside my class.

It seams that the static member is disposed in some way and created again.

Can I control this in some way?

Comment: i tried in [console app](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/log4net-header) but cannot reproduce. did you use `XmlConfigurator` multiple times?

Comment: Is your service hosted in IIS? Maybe the AppPool is being recycled.

Comment: @LeiYang: This was the problem. My constructor called .XmlConfigurator.Configure always.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that I called `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` always when my service object was constrcuted.

I need to do this only once.

```
public class Service : IService, IDisposable
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service));
    private static bool logConfigured = false;
...       
    public Service()
    {
        if (!logConfigured)
        {
            logConfigured = true;
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
    }
```